# Get client RAM memory Value

Tags: jsp, memory, ram

I implimented a JSP page to detect the RAM memory of the user connected to my pages. I used java code :

```
double diskSize = new File("/").getTotalSpace();
String userName = System.getProperty("user.name");
double maxMemory = Runtime.getRuntime().maxMemory();
```

but this code return the disc size of the server.
Thank you to response me

Comment: Yes, Java code in a .jsp runs on the server You cannot run Java code in a .jsp on the browser/client.

Comment: please how to get this information using any language

Comment: You can get it in almost any language you want, and you have code in Java already that does this. You just need to run the code on the client machine. However I suspect you want to do this via a web browser. There's not really anything you can run in a web browser that will leak this information from unsuspecting users to your server though.